# Locally Path Connected space that is not Path Connected.

Tags: general-topology

Can you give me an example of a space that is locally path connected but not path connected, if it exists ?

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting question is are there path connected spaces that aren't locally path connected at any point?

Comment: [This website](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146) is useful for questions like these.

Comment: Wow! I knew about [Topospaces](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/), which has something similar. But the site from @ZevChonoles' comment looks great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple examples include $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ with its natural topology as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, and any set with at least two points with the discrete topology.

Comment: It may also be worth pointing out that this is the only example in a sense: A locally path connected space is path connected iff it is connected.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, the website Zev Chonoles references (called [$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/)) gives the following spaces as locally path connected but not path connected. (It should be noted that this information is also available in Steen and Seebach's [Counterexamples in Topology](http://books.google.com/books/about/Counterexamples_in_Topology.html?id=DkEuGkOtSrUC).) You can learn more about these spaces by viewing the [search result](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%7EPath%20Connected%2BLocally%20Path%20Connected).

Countable Discrete Topology

Either-Or Topology

Finite Discrete Topology

Hjalmar Ekdal Topology

Odd-Even Topology

Sierpinski's Metric Space

Uncountable Discrete Topology